# Binary Search Tree using char type

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I understand Binary Search Tree  on integers ,because i know the left child must be less then the node,and right child must be greater then the node ,when it comes to "char" or "string" type ,its totally different case,we can't say ( 'a' < 'b' ) or any other logical operations .
how can i compare the char values?!

This is my Binary Tree   http://share.pho.to/89JtW i couldn't work because each time i insert to my code.all nodes are inserted to the right of sub-node  .

the nodes represent a pages ,i want to check each page  to detect if user is human or spambot .

each page can be linked to another 2 pages. A human will traverse on the
webpage in a way that it will be able to go to the previous page or one of the next two pages that they  are linked to. Otherwise, they will be categorized as spambot.

And this code i trying to implement

```
    package stringBtree;

public class StringBinaryTreeSample {
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
  new StringBinaryTreeSample().run();
  }
  static class Node 
   {
  Node left;
  Node right;
  char  value;
  public Node(char value) {
  this.value = value;
  }
  }
  public void run() {
  Node rootnode = new Node('A');
  System.out.println("Building tree with rootvalue " + rootnode.value);
  System.out.println("================================="); 
  insert(rootnode, 'b' );
  insert(rootnode, 'd' );
  insert(rootnode, 'c');
  insert(rootnode, 'd');
  insert(rootnode, 'e' );
  insert(rootnode, 'f');
  insert(rootnode, 'g');
  insert(rootnode, 'h');
  insert(rootnode, 'i');
  insert(rootnode, 'j');
  insert(rootnode, 'k');
  insert(rootnode, 'l');
  insert(rootnode, 'm');
  insert(rootnode, 'n');
  insert(rootnode, 'o');
  insert(rootnode, 'p');
  insert(rootnode, 'q');
  System.out.println("\n\nTraversing tree in order");
  System.out.println("=================================");
  printInOrder(rootnode);
  }
  public void insert(Node node, char value) {
    if (value < node.value) {

    if (node.left != null) {
    insert(node.left, value);
    } else {
    System.out.println("  Inserted " + value +   " to left of node " + node.value);
    node.left = new Node(value);
    }

    } else if (value > node.value) {
        if (node.right != null) {
        insert(node.right, value);
        } else {
        System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + "  to right of node " + node.value);
        node.right = new Node(value);
        }
     }
  }
  public void printInOrder(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
    printInOrder(node.left);
    System.out.println("  Traversed " + node.value);
    printInOrder(node.right);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many method to compare string, for instance dictionary order or Hamming Distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), so it is incorrect to state that strings cannot be compared

Comment: oh i see ,which one would you recommended to use ,because i am intermediate in java, also  why when ever i insert a "char" value to this tree it goes directly  to right of sub-node .@Ironluca

Comment: Easiest for you is to String.compare, that follows the natural ordering i.e. dictionary ordering

Comment: Thanks a lot for tips ,what about when i insert a "char" value to this tree it goes directly to right of sub-node.@Ironluca

Comment: a 'char', not Character is essentially a number so >,<,== operators can be used on them

Comment: can you show me how to add the node like the photo " http://share.pho.to/89JtW "i have tried but didn't  get it.@Ironluca

Answer (score 0):

**How to compare chars and strings**

First, I should say that a `char` is not a `string`.  In Java (and many other languages), a `char` is actually a two `byte` number.  Take a look at [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) of characters and you'll see that every character has a unique byte counterpart.  Since a `byte` can be thought of as a number, **you actually can compare chars using the usual comparison operators >, <, and ==.**  **Strings, on the other hand, are objects, so you have to compare them using the `compareTo` method.**  By reading the documentation on Strings, you can find out that the [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) method will return a negative or positive number depending on whether the string is alphabetically before or after the other string you're comparing it to (click on the link to read the documentation for more info).

**Why nodes are always being added to the right**

I'm assuming that you are saying that the nodes that you insert into the tree are always added to the right of the root node.  The root node in your code is the character `A`, which, according to the ASCII table, is actually less than all of the other characters that you add later on since all of the other letters are lowercase.  So that means all of the following nodes are going to be added to the right of `A`.  I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it's worth pointing out.

If you are saying that the nodes are always added to the right of the whole tree (so that it looks like a long line with no branches), that's because of the letters you picked and the order you add them to the tree.  If you follow your code, you add 'b' to 'A'. 'b' > 'A' so it's added to the right. Next you add 'd'. 'd' > 'b' so that node is added to the right.  Then you add 'c', and 'c' < 'd', so that node should be on the left. After that, you add the nodes in alphabetical order, so each subsequent letter you add is greater than the last letter you added.  To illustrate, 'd' < 'e' < 'f' < 'g' < ... < 'q'. Hence, all nodes after 'c' are added to the right.  This makes sense; on the contrary, the tree in the photo you linked to doesn't make sense.  That tree is a binary tree in the sense that each node has only two children, but the child nodes aren't "less" or "greater" than their parent node.  I mean, how is 'B' less than 'A' and at the same time 'C' greater than 'A'? I don't see what you would use that tree for, unless the letters mean something other than their literal characters.

**How to make your tree look like the one in the picture**

If you really wanted to make your tree look like the one in the picture, you would have to assign numbers to the characters so that 'B' is less than 'A', 'C' is greater than 'A', etc.  Then in your `insert` method, you would compare those characters using the number rather than the character.  That could be done by making a class with a character field and a number field.  You would then set the number field to be whatever you wanted to make your tree look like you need it look like.  For instance, 'A' could be 50, 'B' 49, 'C' 51, etc.

Comment: A `byte` in Java is 8 bits, range -128 to 127. A `char` is 16 bits, range 0 to 65535. See the JLS, [4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes, I suppose you're correct. I think, in this case, the distinction between a chat and a byte is subtle if we're talking about ASCII characters, which have values from 0-255.

Comment: I looked back at the question, and I don't see anything saying it is limited to ASCII. The example characters happen to be in the common range, but that does not make the data types the same.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That is certainly true. However, I don't know enough about other character sets to be able to make my answer more general.

Comment: There is no need to drag byte into it at all: "Java `char` is a 16 bit unsigned integer data type, for which the relational operators <, <=, ==, >=, and > are fully supported."

Answer (score 0):

Below is a outline implementation of B-Tree with String:

```
public class TreeNode {

protected String nodeValue;
protected TreeNode leftChild;
protected TreeNode rightChild;

public TreeNode(String nodeValue){

    this.nodeValue=nodeValue;

}//constructor closing

public void addChild(String childNodeValue){

    if(childNodeValue.compareTo(nodeValue)<0){//go left

        if(leftChild==null)leftChild=new TreeNode(childNodeValue);
        else {

            if(childNodeValue.compareTo(leftChild.getNodeValue())<0)leftChild.addChild(childNodeValue);
            else{

                TreeNode tempChild=new TreeNode(childNodeValue);
                tempChild.setLeftChild(this.leftChild);
                this.leftChild=tempChild;

            }//else closing

        }//else closing

    }//if closing
    else if(childNodeValue.compareTo(nodeValue)>0){//go right

        if(rightChild==null)rightChild=new TreeNode(childNodeValue);
        else {


            if(childNodeValue.compareTo(rightChild.getNodeValue())>0)rightChild.addChild(childNodeValue);
            else{

                TreeNode tempChild=new TreeNode(childNodeValue);
                tempChild.setRightChild(this.rightChild);
                this.rightChild=tempChild;

            }//else closing

        }//else closing

    }//if closing
    else throw new RuntimeException("Problem");

}//addChild closing

public String getNodeValue(){return nodeValue;}
public TreeNode getLeftChild(){return leftChild;}
public TreeNode getRightChild(){return rightChild;}
public void setLeftChild(TreeNode leftChild){this.leftChild=leftChild;}
public void setRightChild(TreeNode rightChild){this.rightChild=rightChild;}

@Override
public String toString() {

    String retVal="--"+nodeValue+"--\n";

    return retVal;

}//toString closing
```

}//class closing

```
public class BTree {

protected TreeNode primaryNode;

public BTree(String primaryNodeValue){

    primaryNode=new TreeNode(primaryNodeValue);

}//constructor closing

public void addChild(String childNodeValue){

    primaryNode.addChild(childNodeValue);

}//addChild closing

public TreeNode getPrimayNode(){return primaryNode;}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return primaryNode.toString();

}//toString closing

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String midValue="m";

    BTree tree=new BTree(midValue);

    tree.addChild("a");
    tree.addChild("b");
    tree.addChild("y");
    tree.addChild("z");

    TreeNode mNode=tree.getPrimayNode();
    TreeNode leftOfMNode=mNode.getLeftChild();
    TreeNode rightOfMNode=mNode.getRightChild();

    System.out.print(mNode);
    System.out.print(leftOfMNode);
    System.out.print(rightOfMNode);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    TreeNode bNode=leftOfMNode;
    System.out.print(bNode);
    System.out.print(bNode.getLeftChild());
    System.out.print(bNode.getRightChild());
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");

    TreeNode yNode=rightOfMNode;
    System.out.print(yNode);
    System.out.print(yNode.getLeftChild());
    System.out.print(yNode.getRightChild());

}//main closing
```

}//class closing

This should give you a head start with your actual implementation.